# Python: sorted(list) command not sorting all values

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I'm attempting to read in a csv file and then sort the file. The file is approximately 25,000 lines long, but when I execute the commands below the outfile is about 500 lines shorter. I'm first sorting by a column in descending order and then 3 in ascending order.  Any ideas why I end up losing data? I would appreciate any thoughts anybody had. Thanks.

```
    infile2=csv.reader(open("im1.csv"), delimiter=",")
    sortedlist=sorted(infile2, key=operator.itemgetter(3), reverse=True)
    sortedlist2=sorted(sortedlist, key=operator.itemgetter(0,1,2), reverse=False)
    with open("im2.csv","w") as output:
            writer=csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
            writer.writerows(sortedlist2)
```

Edit: Problem fixed, I had simply forgotten to close a file earlier in the program and therefore wasn't sorting as many elements as I thought I was.

Comment: Mark this up with some print calls to be sure it isn't just a problem with flushing output. `print len(sortedlist)`, `print len(sortedlist2)`, and compare the two to the length of your input and output files.

Comment: ...it'll be a lot easier to understand the bug if we know if you're losing the content on input, on output, or in processing. (If it's the former, I'd check for NULs or EOF characters in the input file).

Comment: If you are on windows and there are EOF characters in the file, you'll need to open the file in binary mode.

Comment: Note, if you don't need to do anything with "sortedlist" itself, you can use .sort() functions to do in-place sorts.  This will be faster and save you memory by not allocating/copying 2 duplicate lists.  It is also possible to use a lambda as your key to combine the two sorts into one.